# Getting check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

Going through Lynda's 2010 tutorial on rails and have been stuck on migration for the past couple of days. When running

$ rake db:migrate

I get

NOC-4:app noc$ rake db:migrate
(in /Users/noc/rails_projects/app)
==  CreateUsers: migrating ====================================================
-- create_table(:users)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql::ServerError::ParseError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1: CREATE TABLE `users` (`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `first_name` varchar(25), `last_name` varchar(50), `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, `created_at` datetime, `updated_at` datetime, `password` varchar(#)) ENGINE=InnoDB

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

=================================

NOC-4:app noc$ mysql --version

## mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.20, for osx10.6 (i386) using readline 5.1

Below is my migrate file (create_users.rb):

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def self.up
     create_table :users do |t|
       t.string "first_name", :limit => 25
       t.string "last_name", :limit => 50
       t.string "email", :default => "", :null => false
       t.string "password", :limit =>
       t.timestamps
     end
   end

   def self.down
     drop_table :users
   end
 end
```

========================================

My rails version and gem list below:

```
NOC-4:app noc$ rails --version
Rails 3.1.3
NOC-4:app noc$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.1.3)
actionpack (3.1.3)
activemodel (3.1.3)
activerecord (3.1.3)
activeresource (3.1.3)
activesupport (3.1.3)
ansi (1.4.1)
arel (2.2.1)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.0.21 ruby)
coffee-rails (3.1.1)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.2.13)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
jquery-rails (1.0.19)
json (1.6.4)
libv8 (3.3.10.4 x86_64-darwin-11)
mail (2.3.0)
mime-types (1.17.2)
multi_json (1.0.4)
mysql (2.8.1)
pg (0.12.2)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.3.6)
rack-cache (1.1)
rack-mount (0.8.3)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.1.3)
railties (3.1.3)
rake (0.8.7)
rdoc (3.12)
ruby-mysql (2.9.4)
sass (3.1.12)
sass-rails (3.1.5)
sprockets (2.0.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.5)
therubyracer (0.9.9)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
turn (0.8.2)
tzinfo (0.3.31)
uglifier (1.2.1)
```

=========================================================

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to complete the limit for your password field.

```
   def self.up
     create_table :users do |t|
       t.string "first_name", :limit => 25
       t.string "last_name", :limit => 50
       t.string "email", :default => "", :null => false
       t.string "password", :limit => 32 # you're missing the value here
       t.timestamps
     end
   end
```

The problem is that `t.timestamps` ends up being the value for your limit, as you can read from the resulting sql in the error explanation: `password varchar(#)) ENGINE=InnoDB`

NOTE: you shouldn't use a plain text field for a password. If you're using rails 3.1 this could help you with this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1

Comment: Wow. I'm with stupid. Thank you sir and for the quick response. 1st question on this site and am amazed at the speed. I'll surely give back once I know more. Cheers :)

Comment: welcome to the best q/a sites on the net, you're gonna like it (and you'll like rails too)